# minikube service URL not working in NodePort and Loadbalancer unless port-forwarding use how to make it work on direct url from minikube

Tags: minikube

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-test-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: phptest
```

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: phptest
  labels:
    app: phptest
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: phptest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: phptest
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: phptest
        image: shehmil/phptest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80


|-----------|------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |       NAME       | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | php-test-service | http/80     | http://192.168.49.2:30736 |
|-----------|------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Opening service default/php-test-service in default browser...
  http://192.168.49.2:30736
```

I've created an svc and deployment manifest.After checking the minikube service url in the browser, it is not loading unless port-forwarding.How does it work without port-forwarding? I tried several times using Loadbalance and NodePort but it didn't work for me.